# Geolocation Using Ionic Cordova Returning Incorrect Lat/Long Values

Tags: geolocation, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am facing issue using Geolocation pluggin with Ionic and Cordova framework.

Using Visual Studio Community 2015, with Cordova CLI version :4.3.0 and added the org.apache.cordova.geolocation pluggin to VSC-2015

My controller.js

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {  
function onSuccess(position) {            
        console.log(position.timestamp);
        console.log(position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude);
    }
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);


 })
```

Added the google maps into the index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&v=3.exp"></script>
```

Added a Map to my Map.html file

```
<div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true" map> </div>
```

The problem is I always get a fixed value of Lat/Long 
ie Lat = 43.465187 and Long = -80.522372

This is not my correct Geolocation in terms of Lat/Long.I need my current Geolocation in terms of Lat/Long

Please help me identity the fault.

Also I am using Ripple -Nexus (Galaxy) on Browser.

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks,

Comment: can you try in mobile devices, instead of using simulator's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Latest version of GeoLocation pluggin from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Then inject the *$cordovaGeolocation* into the controller.
Code is as below:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaGeolocation) {
$scope.getLocation = function() {      
  var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
    $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function (position) {
        //these are your your lat long values  
        var lat  = position.coords.latitude
        var long = position.coords.longitude                        
        }, function(err) {
        // error           
       });
      }
    })
```

Note: The device need to be connected to internet or wifi and also need to keep the GPS location ON in the device for getting the correct Lat/Long Values.

Comment: i used this library but sometime get wrong location

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you get fixed lat/long values. However to get the device's position using Ionic, the following works for me:

```
ionic.Platform.ready($scope.getLocation);

$scope.getLocation = function () {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($scope.showPosition, $scope.showError);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
    }
}

$scope.showPosition = function (position) {
 console.log(position.timestamp);
 console.log(position.coords.latitude + ' ' + position.coords.longitude);
}

$scope.showError = function (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.log('User denied the request for Geolocation.');
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            console.log('Location information is unavailable.');
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            console.log('The request to get user location timed out.');
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            console.log('An unknown error occurred.');
            break;
    }
}
```

Note that the call to:

```
ionic.Platform.ready($scope.getLocation);
```

Is crucial, as you can only guarantee you'll get an accurate GPS fix once the device is ready/initialised.

Comment: Tried the above technique as well, gives the following error:


Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaGeolocationProvider <- $cordovaGeolocation <- MapCtrl



http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaGeolocationProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaGeolocation%20%3C-%20MapCtrl

Comment: Ah, that's because the example I wrote is for Cordova. I'll update my answer for ionic when I get back from vacation.

Comment: Hi @Mufaddal, sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I've re-wrote my answer using Ionic instead of Cordova. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I identified the problem, though it may sound stupid but the problem was to get the correct Lat/Long values, the device need to be connected to internet or wifi and also need to keep the GPS location ON in the device.